# asset() function in twig gives an NotFoundHttpException "No route found for "GET /favicon.ico"

Tags: symfony-3.3

I have just installed a new Symfony project (I use `xampp`). When I started the application the favicon on the url tab wasn't showing, i opened the source code and opend the icon from there, but I got the error message I writed in the title.
In the code the link is presented as:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
```

and in the source code it was like

```
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

What is the problem, am I missing something ? 
Thanks

Comment: Which Symfony version are you using? It can't be both 1 and 2.

Comment: Symfony 3.3, i just selected that so i can get the answer faster, i tought it is the same thing when it comes to this problem. Sry

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

you should put the file in the web folder

the asset function target a folder web by default. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html

Comment: Care to expand?

Comment: It is in the web folder "web -> favicon.ico" ... I just installed the project, I didn't touch anything. The .ico file is by default in the web folder